# Apipie receiving integer param as String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, apipie

I have the following RSpec test:

```
 it 'should not list alerts, since I do not have access to this model' do
   get :index, params: { model_id: @model2.id, workspace_id: @workspace.id }, as: :json
   expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
 end
```

and it is failing because Apipie is complaining the `workspace_id` is a String when it is actually not, it is an Integer. I debugged the call, inspected `@workspace` and `id` is definitely an Integer.

I'm seeing this issue now that I'm migrating the application to Rails 5.2.0 (previously Rails 4).

Has anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GET` request doesn't contains body, while you're trying to send some payload. In the case of `GET` request all params passed as  url query (e.g. `/index?model_id=1&workspace_id=1`) and all params are string.

You have two options here:

- Change `GET` to `POST`, it will allow request with body.
- Convert string to integer in the action.

Comment: nope. the apipie validation can actually see that the workspace_id is 1, but see it as an integer, so the `params` are not sent through the body, they are being sent via query param

Comment: There is no types in url query params, all url-query params are strings.

Comment: who knows, that's an open-source lib, inspect changelogs, the issues, maybe some changes happened.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I hit the same problem.  I am using Rack::Test with rspec, and Rack::Test is automagically (bug) converting every value to a string.  Not sure what other back-end bits also do this.

The only way I found to get rack-test to send anything other than strings as values, was by overriding the request methods as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234290/2326613

There is also a problem where BigDecimal values are being forced into strings by "as: :json" - not affecting the OP (IDs being Integers) but could be others finding this question by search.  The workaround to fix *that* bug was depreciated and removed by the Rails team.  So, to be able to follow JSON conventions which your JSON-consumer may expect (vs Rails conventions), you need to override the BigDecimal-as_json method to fix it:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25017

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same integer converted to string issue while making a `POST/PUT/PATCH` request.
If you pass the `params` converted with `to_json` and pass `'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'` as env, `integer` will be passed as is to the controller.

```rb
let(:params) do
  {
    down_payment: 10_000,
    asking_price: 100_000,
    payment_schedule: 'weekly',
    amortization_period: 5
  }
end

it 'works' do
  post '/', params.to_json, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
end
```

This will work as expected.