# Rails 5.2.3 converting all params datatype to string when testing using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.2.3 and testing using rspec-rails (3.8.2), when I send request to rails like this

```
  let(:params) do
    {
      down_payment: 10_000,
      asking_price: 100_000,
      payment_schedule: 'weekly',
      amortization_period: 5
    }
  end
  it 'works' do
    get :calculate, params: params, format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end
```

I also tried

```
  it 'works' do
    get :calculate, params: params, as: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end
```

in rails all integers get converted to string like this

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"amortization_period"=>"5", "asking_price"=>"100000", "down_payment"=>"10000", "payment_schedule"=>"weekly", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"payment_amount", "action"=>"calculate", "payment_amount"=>{}} permitted: false>
```

But if I use curl to send a request I can see integer not being converted to string.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d ‘{"asking_price": 100000 ,"payment_schedule": "monthly", "down_payment": 10000, "amortization_period": 5  }' http://localhost:3000/payment-amount
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you sending them with curl that they are not being converted to string? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @maxpleaner Please see my updates. I have added `curl` command

Comment: Because curl works like it is supposed to - follows the JSON standard - not what the rails-team thinks everyone "should be doing," and never mind most of the machines we interact with API-wise don't adhere to their religion.

Comment: Note - same problem using rack-test on backend - the post method takes  your json and adds backslashed-strings.  If you use to: :json, it doesn't send the backslashes, but still converts your non-string values to strings, so no POSTs with integers being sent can ever be tested.

Comment: Found a solution - posted to answer another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57566937/2326613

Answer (score 4):

JSON payloads can contain [five value types](https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/basic_types/): `string`, `number`, `integer`, `boolean` and `null`.

HTTP query strings are, by contrast, *only **strings***.

By default, request specs use the encoding specified in the HTTP spec - i.e. *all parameters are strings*. This is why you see the parameters get converted.

If your production system is sending `JSON`, you need to tell the test to do so too - e.g. by adding `as: :json` as you did above.

Comment: Thanks, why I added `as: :json` it is still converting params to string?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When I add `as_json`, I get integers. Maybe you're using some extra library (that you haven't mentioned) which changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `as: :json` format to your requests

```
post(graphql_path, params: params, as: :json)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries, I found the solution to this issue. If you pass the `params` converted with `to_json` and pass `'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'` as env, `integers` will be passed to the controller.

```rb
let(:params) do
  {
    down_payment: 10_000,
    asking_price: 100_000,
    payment_schedule: 'weekly',
    amortization_period: 5
  }
end

it 'works' do
  post '/', params.to_json, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
end
```

This will work as expected.